# database is not configured. Available: [] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Trying to configure multiple databases to put logs differently in an different database

---

```
default: 
  adapter: mysql2
  host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  password: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
development: 
  adapter: mysql2
  database: abc
  encoding: utf8
  host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  password: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
log_database_development: 
  adapter: mysql2
  database: abc_logs
  encoding: utf8
  host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  password: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
log_database_test: 
  adapter: mysql2
  database: abc_logs
  encoding: utf8
  host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  password: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
test: 
  adapter: mysql2
  database: abc
  encoding: utf8
  host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  password: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
```

but when i am trying to run

> rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

i am getting exception

```
ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'log_database_development' database is not configured. Available: [] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

my model which is trying to access this database is

```
class AccessLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "log_database_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

now i am not getting what is wrong in my model or connection, Can you please help me out ?

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When providing the argument of a configured section to `establish_connection` you need to provide it as a symbol:

```
establish_connection :"log_database_#{Rails.env}"
```

or...

```
establish_connection "log_database_#{Rails.env}".to_sym
```